# APT update fails: writing more data than expected

Tags: apt, 16.04

when trying to update package listings via `apt update` or `apt-get update` I receive the following error:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.gz  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Writing more data than expected (7468511 > 7467723) [IP: 193.219.61.87 80]
```

Is this somehow related to localised package distributor or is me all along? I am running beta2 release, that I've successfully installed and updated (without any error prompts) yesterday. Previously I used a 14.04 derivative which also did not bring up any errors.
What can be the reason for this error?

EDIT: to duplicate markers, the topic name tackles a different problem rather than the hash sum problem, which is being referenced.

Comment: 16.04 has not been officially released yet. This question is off topic.

Comment: I solved it by changing the mirrors as mentioned in [16.04 apt update一直无法成功](http://forum.ubuntu.org.cn/viewtopic.php?f=77&p=3163436#p3163436 ) Sorry it's in Chinese...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you've been accessing the local repo mirror while being updated.
Wait some time (usually 1 hour is enough) before trying again.
This can happen to all live releases, not just 16.04 (which is not officially out yet, as commented by someone else).

As an option, you could edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to expunge the "lt" prefix with your favorite editor or use

```
sudo sed -i 's/http:\/\/lt\./http:\/\//g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This will make you access the main repositories at the cost of a slower access.

Of course, you can replace `lt` with your very own ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code.

Comment: Thanks, it seemed to be a slow mirror update, as both localised and main repository had the same update errors

Comment: This did not work for me

Answer (score 8):

Add a parameter that adds a 'no-cache' header to the http/https requests. It asks the apt server to provide un-cached files. This can be useful if there are any kind of (broken) caching mechanism between your machine and apt mirror/server. (Such as proxy, transparent caching by ISP etc)

```
sudo apt -o Acquire::https::No-Cache=True -o Acquire::http::No-Cache=True update
```

just run this command in your terminal and it should work just fine

Comment: Please provide a broader explanation on what your offered command does

Comment: @PauliusŠukys I believe that adds a 'no-cache' header to the http/https requests. It asks the apt server to provide un-cached files. This can be useful if there are any kind of (broken) caching mechanism between your machine and apt mirror/server. (Such as proxy, transparent caching by ISP etc)

Comment: This worked for me and the explanation by @Shyam makes sense, even though I agree it would be nice to have a more insightful answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Mint.