# 16.04 officially release APT update always fails

Tags: 16.04

it report "writing more data than expected"
I use officially release 16.04, and try to change to different repo mirror, still not work well. I use http/https proxy to access internet in office, it always fail. But I install it in my home, it worked well. Is there some problem behind proxy?

14.04 is both good whatever in home or office.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [APT update fails: writing more data than expected](http://askubuntu.com/questions/751801/apt-update-fails-writing-more-data-than-expected)

Comment: I see this, but I try to do as this talk's way, but it still not work.